# How can I find the Firefox window from xwininfo?

Tags: perl, firefox, mozilla

My Perl isn't very good at all and I am having trouble determining why [this](http://marginalhacks.com/bin/html2jpg) awesome perl script keeps returning:

> Error: No running window found
>   Couldn't find window [Mozilla] in
>   [xwininfo -tree -root]

I have setup these variables:

```
my $PROGNAME = $0;
$PROGNAME =~ s|.*/||;
my $GRAB = 'xwd -silent -nobdrs -id %id | convert -quality 85 - %out';
my $XINFO = 'xwininfo -tree -root';
my $BROWSER = 'firefox';    # Must match find_window() code - see usage()
```

In usage it says this:

```
- Requires "Mozilla" or "Opera" browser
    (update find_window() code for other browsers)
```

The code concerned is this:

```
# I'm using mozilla..
sub find_window {
  $BROWSER eq "opera" ?
    opera_find_window(@_) :
    mozilla_find_window(@_);
}
```

How would I get the above to reflect a firefox browser. In my shell, if I type mozilla nothing happens, if i type firefox - my browser opens, so I should be using this.

Here is the code in question which returns that error:

```
sub mozilla_find_window {
  open(XINFO,"$XINFO|") || die("Couldn't run: [$XINFO]\n");

  # Pick the first mozilla window.  It's got the title in it, but
  # we have no way of knowing if that matches the URL, so we'll
  # hope this is the right one..
  my ($spacing,$id,$title,$x,$y);
  while(<XINFO>) {
    # This could easily break and is very mozilla specific (works on firefox)
    # Looks for [...("Mozilla" "navigator:browser") ..]
    # I've had this reported:     0x80002f "TITLE - Mozilla": ("Gecko" "Mozilla-bin")  889x687+0+22  +136+44
    last if (($spacing,$id,$title,$x,$y) = (/^(\s+)(0x[0-9a-f]+) "(.*)\s*-\s*Mozilla.*": \("Mozilla" "navigator:browser"\)\s*$GEOM_RE$/));

    last if (($spacing,$id,$title,$x,$y) = (/^(\s+)(0x[0-9a-f]+) "(.*)\s*-\s*Mozilla.*": \("mozilla-bin" "Mozilla-bin"\)\s*$GEOM_RE$/));
    # Mozilla Firefox 1.0.4
    last if (($spacing,$id,$title,$x,$y) = (/^(\s+)(0x[0-9a-f]+) "(.*)\s*-\s*Mozilla Firefox.*": \("Gecko" "Firefox-bin"\)\s*$GEOM_RE$/));
        # Debian Mozilla Firefox
        last if (($spacing,$id,$title,$x,$y) = (/^(\s+)(0x[0-9a-f]+) "(.*)\s*-\s*Mozilla Firefox.*": \("firefox-bin" "Firefox-bin"\)\s*$GEOM_RE$/));
  }
  die("Couldn't find window [Mozilla] in [$XINFO]\n") unless $title && $x && $y;
```

Anybody know how I can fix this, what I am doing wrong? It is a problem that is to do with the location where by firefox is installed?

Thanks all

### Update

> ```
>  0x140529c "Firefox": ()  10x10+-100+-100  +-100+-100
>  0x14051b9 "Firefox": ()  10x10+-100+-100  +-100+-100
>  0x14038c9 "Firefox": ("firefox" "Firefox")  1x1+-100+-100  +-100+-100
>     1 child:
>     0x14038ca (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +-101+-101
>  0x14002bd "Firefox": ()  1x1+0+0  +0+0
>     1 child:
>     0x14002be (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +-1+-1
>  0x1400210 "Firefox": ()  10x10+-100+-100  +-100+-100
>  0x14000ea "Firefox": ("firefox" "Firefox")  200x200+0+0  +0+0
>     1 child:
>     0x14000eb (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +-1+-1
>  0x14000a6 "Firefox": ("firefox" "Firefox")  200x200+0+0  +0+0
>     2 children:
>     0x14000a9 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +-1+-1
>        1 child:
>        0x14000aa (has no name): ()  1x1+2+2  +1+1
>           1 child:
>           0x14000ab (has no name): ()  1x1+0+0  +1+1
>              4 children:
>              0x140519f (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +0+0
>              0x140519e (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +0+0
>              0x1400286 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +0+0
>              0x14000ad (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +0+0
>     0x14000a7 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +-1+-1
>  0x140008d "Firefox": ("firefox" "Firefox")  200x200+0+0  +0+0
> ```

The above is obtained when I run this manually `xwininfo -tree -root`

Comment: It doesn't look like that would have anything to do with where your firefox is installed, as it's just looking at the titles of open X windows. What is the output of xwininfo -tree -root at the time you run the script?

Comment: I am really crap at perl, so I am not sure if I did this right. I put "print $XINFO" after the open in the sub mozilla_find_window. It returned "xwininfo -tree -root". I am guessing I am doing this correctly! Apologies.

Comment: Well, $XINFO is just the variable containing the actual command that this script attempts to run(at `open(XINFO, "$XINFO|"`). So perl is attempting to run `xwininfo -tree -root` and then to go through the output of that command (during the while loop.) Therefore it would help if we knew what is actually output by `xwininfo -tree -root` when the script runs. If you could run that command yourself and paste the output here, or at least look through it so you can make sense of what perl is looking through, it would be easier to solve this.

Comment: Ah I see, so its looking for instances of firefox in the running programmes. So those regular expressions are having difficulty finding a match. I have put the output of that command I have run (part of it only).

Comment: That's right. Try my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see from the output of `xwininfo` that your Firefox shows up in the X window list as **"Firefox": ("firefox" "Firefox")**.

None of your regexes are currently looking for this combination. Add this code directly after the `#Debian Mozilla Firefox` lines (or at least somewhere in that same `while` block):

```
# my Firefox
last if (($spacing,$id,$title,$x,$y) = (/^(\s+)(0x[0-9a-f]+) "(Firefox)": \("firefox" "Firefox"\)\s*$GEOM_RE$/));
```

Comment: The above has got it to pass that error point! Thanks. I am faced with a new error now, I will try fixing this first, if not, I'll be back!